# Evaluate glue inside data.frame

Tags: r, r-glue

I'm trying to evaluate a `glue` template row by row inside a data.frame.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
expand_grid(var1 = c("A", "B"),
            var2 = c("x", "y", "z")) %>%
  full_join(data.frame(text_model = c("First {var1} and then {var2}", 
                                       "First {var2} and then {var1}"))
            , by = character()) %>%
  mutate(text_output = glue(text_model))
```

Here the `text_output` creation doesn't work. Any advice ?

Comment: Add `rowwise()` between the join and mutate commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ritchie, I'll accept that if you post as answer